Torch backward PowBackward0 causes nan gradient where it shouldn't
I have a pytorch tensor with NaN inside, when I calculate the loss function using a simple MSE Loss the gradient becomes NaN even if I mask out the NaN values.
Weirdly this happens only when the mask is applyied after calculating the loss and only when the loss has a pow operation inside. The various cases follow
import torch
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

x = torch.rand(10, 10) 
y = torch.rand(10, 10)
w = torch.rand(10, 10, requires_grad=True)
y[y > 0.5] = torch.nan


o = w @ x
l = (y - o)**2
l = l[~y.isnan()]

try:
    l.mean().backward(retain_graph=True)
except RuntimeError:
    print('(y-o)**2 caused nan gradient')

l = (y - o)
l = l[~y.isnan()]

try:
    l.mean().backward(retain_graph=True)
except RuntimeError():
    pass
else:
    print('y-o does not cause nan gradient')

l = (y[~y.isnan()] - o[~y.isnan()])**2
l.mean().backward()
print('masking before pow does not propagate nan gradient')

What makes NaN gradients propagate when passing through the backward pass of the pow function?

The nans don't come from the gradient, the nans come from the forward pass. These are multiplied by gradient values in the backward pass (chain rule).
Take a simpler example. Set exactly one value in y to nan:
x = torch.rand(10, 10) 
y = torch.rand(10, 10)
w = torch.rand(10, 10, requires_grad=True)
y[0,0] = torch.nan

Now compute your intermediates and retain gradients
o = w@x
o.retain_grad()

l = (y - o).pow(2)
l.retain_grad()

l_nonnan = l[~y.isnan()]
l_nonnan.retain_grad()

l_nonnan.mean().backward()

Inspect the gradients

l_nonnan has full gradients
l has full gradients except for l.grad[0,0] which is 0
o has a nan gradient at o.grad[0,0]
w has nan gradients for the entire first row

This is due to how the computation propagates. We set y[0,0] = torch.nan. We compute l = (y - o).pow(2) this means o[0,0] is nan because it directly interacts with the nan from y.
o is created via o = w@x. This means the value at o[0,0] = (w[0] * x[:,0]).sum(). When we run the computation in reverse in backprop, the gradient of o[0,0] (which we know to be nan) propagates back to all ements of w[0]. This is why the entire row has nan gradients.
When you set a bunch of nans randomly, you get the same effect on more elements.
You can avoid this via l = (y[~y.isnan()] - o[~y.isnan()])**2 because when you do that you prevent the nans in y from entering the computation in the first place.

I understand that allowing nans in the forward computation leads to nans in the backward computation, but when we index select we should mask out all gradient values that have interacted with nan's thus eliminating nans while backpropagating?
Also this does not explain why the version with only the subtraction and not the pow works

Think about the chain rule. At the step (y-o).pow(2), the gradient is l_nonnan * 2 * (y - o). (y - o) contains the nan value in y[0,0]. This gradient then propagates backward to previous layers. The index select masks values after the index select, not before. The (y[~y.isnan()] - o[~y.isnan()])**2 approach works because the nan values are never introduced in the first place

this does not explain why
l = l[~y.isnan()]``` works

That works because the gradient function is different. It has nothing to do with the indexing. When you compute (y-o).pow(2), your gradient is 2*(y-o) which includes all of y, propagating the nan. When you compute y-o, your gradient (wrt o, propagating into w) is -1 - the y tensor does not participate. I would suggest studying how the chain rule works
